# scala-pickling in POJO in scala 2.11 - Is it really simple?

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

I'm trying to use scala-pickling because at site [github](https://github.com/scala/pickling) it seems so easy and clean. But, I'm failing in use it in this simple **REPL**:

```
scala> import scala.pickling._
import scala.pickling._

scala> import scala.pickling.Defaults._
import scala.pickling.Defaults._

scala> import binary._
import binary._

scala> class Xpto { var a = 0D; var b = 0 }
defined class Xpto

scala> val v = new Xpto { a = 1.23; b = 5 }
v: Xpto = $anon$1@636d2b03

scala> v.pickle
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : v.type (with underlying type Xpto)
 required: ?{def pickle: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method PickleOps in package pickling of type [T](picklee: T)pickling.PickleOps[T]
 and method pickleOps in trait Ops of type [T](picklee: T)scala.pickling.PickleOps[T]
 are possible conversion functions from v.type to ?{def pickle: ?}
          v.pickle
            ^
<console>:19: error: value pickle is not a member of Xpto
                  v.pickle
                    ^
```

What is wrong?

I did access other issues on StackOverflow with this same type of question, for example:

[Scala pickling: Simple custom pickler for my own class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832563/scala-pickling-simple-custom-pickler-for-my-own-class)

Obs.: I'm using this reference in **build.sbt**:

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.10.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that those are the **only** imports you are using when in the REPL?  The error above is, as it says:

> Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
>    both method PickleOps in package pickling of type [T](picklee: T)pickling.PickleOps[T]
>    and method pickleOps in trait Ops of type [T](picklee: T)scala.pickling.PickleOps[T]
>    are possible conversion functions from v.type to ?{def pickle: ?}

So you have at least two implicit conversions, from `scala.pickling.PickleOps[T]()` and `scala.pickling.Ops.pickleOps`.  This is strange, because [PickleOps](https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/8677e90713075af75c06e01bc456f84e62491d64/core/src/main/scala/scala/pickling/Ops.scala#L7-L18) is not an implicit class.

For me it works `(Scala version 2.11.7 Java 1.7.0_79)` in a fresh REPL:

```
scala> import scala.pickling._
scala> import scala.pickling.Defaults._
scala> import binary._
scala> class Xpto { var a = 0D; var b = 0 }
defined class Xpto
scala> val v = new Xpto { a = 1.23; b = 5 }
v: Xpto = cmd5$$anonfun$1$$anon$1@244da0ed
scala> v.pickle
res6: pickleFormat.PickleType = BinaryPickle([0,0,0,23,99,109,100,53,36,36,97,110,111,110,102,117,110,36,49,36,36,97,110,111,110,36,49,63,-13,-82,20,122,-31,71,-82,0,0,0,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Great! It runs!

I started a new fresh scala console.

I was using this reference to scala.pickling in build.sbt:

```
"org.scala-lang" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.10.1"
```

and now I'm using

```
"org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.10.1"
```

I'm also utilising Scala 2.11.6

Now it works perfectly, and really it's so simple.

```
scala> import scala.pickling._
import scala.pickling._

scala> import scala.pickling.binary._
import scala.pickling.binary._

scala> import scala.pickling.Defaults._
import scala.pickling.Defaults._

scala> class Xpto { var a = 0D; var b = 0; }
defined class Xpto

scala> val v = new Xpto { a = 1.23; b = 4; }
v: Xpto = $anon$1@1e7bd4df

scala> v.pickle
res0: pickling.binary.pickleFormat.PickleType = BinaryPickle([0,0,0,52,46,108,105,110,101,55,46,46,114,101,97,100,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,105,119,46,46,97,110,111,110,46,49,63,-13,-82,20,122,-31,71,-82,0,0,0,4])
```

I don't now if my others libraries references was generating that ambiguous refence. My references in **build.sbt** are:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17",
  "javax.transaction" % "jta" % "1.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.10",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0-SNAP4" % "test",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.11",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.9",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.10.1"
)
```

Thanks to Markus.