# Custom unpickler fails with "NoSuchElementException: : key not found: value"

Tags: scala, jodatime, scala-pickling

I'm trying to pickle/unpickle a joda DateTime instance to/from json with pickling. With pickling 0.8.0, if I don't supply a custom pickler, I get

```
JSONPickle({
  "tpe": "org.joda.time.DateTime"
})
```

When I do:

```
class DateTimePickler(implicit val format: PickleFormat) extends
  SPickler[DateTime] with Unpickler[DateTime] {
    private val stringUnpickler = implicitly[Unpickler[String]]

    def pickle(picklee: DateTime, builder: PBuilder): Unit = {
      builder.beginEntry(picklee)
      builder.putField("date", b =>
        b.hintTag(stringTag).beginEntry(picklee.toString).endEntry()
      )
      builder.endEntry()
    }

    override def unpickle(tag: => FastTypeTag[_], reader: PReader): DateTime = {
      reader.hintTag(stringTag)
      val tag = reader.beginEntry()
      logger.debug(s"tag is ${tag.toString}")
      val value = stringUnpickler.unpickle(tag, reader).asInstanceOf[String] //can't debug NoSuchElementException: : key not found: value
      logger.debug(s"value is $value")
      reader.endEntry()

      val timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault
      DateTime.parse(value).withZone(timeZone) //otherwise the parsed DateTime won't equal the original
    }
  }

  implicit def genDateTimePickler(implicit format: PickleFormat) = new DateTimePickler
```

I get

```
JSONPickle({
  "tpe": "org.joda.time.DateTime",
  "date": {
    "tpe": "java.lang.String",
    "value": "2014-09-16T17:59:25.865+03:00"
  }
})
```

and unpickling fails with NoSuchElementException: : key not found: value. With pickling 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT my specs2 test won't even terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pickling at the moment suffers from lack of documentation and uninformative error messages. Anyway, my unpickle method was written analogous to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227949/2327550), and it assumed binary serialization. The correct unpickle method found by trial and error looks like this:

```
override def unpickle(tag: => FastTypeTag[_], reader: PReader): DateTime = {
  val dateReader = reader.readField("date")
  val tag = dateReader.beginEntry()
  val value = stringUnpickler.unpickle(tag, dateReader).asInstanceOf[String]
  dateReader.endEntry()

  val timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault
  DateTime.parse(value).withZone(timeZone) //otherwise the parsed DateTime won't equal the original
}
```